# Is there any easy way to tell if an element is shown in CSS?

Tags: css

```html
<div style="display: none;">
   <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
// getComputedStyle(div).display === 'none';

const span = document.querySelector('span');
// how can I tell if the span is shown?
```

In the code above, is there any easy way to tell whether the span is shown in the window or not?

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? `const` does not look like CSS to me

Comment: That's Javascript code.

Comment: Duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/q/123999/8583669

Comment: Thanks @johannchopin, so it looks like there's no easy way in CSS selector?

Comment: I think you could also go to the parent and check the display attribute there.
document.querySelect('span').parentElement...

Comment: @nosTa, yeah, I actually have to go recursively to all ancestors, if there's no other easier ways, or using johannchopin's recommendation to test the element bounding box values.

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: @QianChen I think it's just impossible with css only

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do this is to use an intersection observer.

```
let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Comment: This is not related to my question, but it's very interesting. It looks like it will notify when some value changes?